# What is MS-Membership Transitive.LDF?

Tags: active-directory, ad-lds

When installing ad-lds, you have the option to import several LDF files. Some of them are described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771943.aspx.

Can anyone tell me what the MS-Membership Transitive.LDF file is all about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It adds support for the new [`ms-DS-Member-Transitive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn365210.aspx) (LDAP display name `msds-memberTransitive`) schema attribute. This attribute contains the contents of the `Member` attribute for the object and all the `Member` attributes of *those* objects in the `Member` attribute (and objects specified in *their* `Member` attribute). Basically, it contains the fully-expanded group membership of the object.